# EF Include and ThenInclude

Tags: entity-framework

I have a few models I am trying to bind with Include which is not returning back all expected related data.  The full chain is:

User (one) > Role (one) > Permissions (Many) > Entity (One) > EntityArea (One)

These are my models: (CompanyBase is a base class with a companyId in it)

```
public class User : _CompanyBase
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }
    }


 public class Role : _CompanyBase
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int RoleID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<RolePermission> RolePermissions { get; set; }

        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }


 public class RolePermission : _CompanyBase
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int RolePermissionID { get; set; }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string PermissionCode { get; set; }



        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }



        public int EntityID { get; set; }
        public Entity Entity { get; set; }


    }

public class Entity : _CompanyBase
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int EntityID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }


        public int EntityAreaID { get; set; }

        public EntityArea EntityArea { get; set; }


    }

public class EntityArea :_CompanyBase
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int EntityAreaID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Name { get; set; }


        public ICollection<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    }
```

And I am trying to bind them with:

```
dbUser = db.Users
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Where(x => x.UserId == UserID)
                    .Include(m => m.Role)
                    .ThenInclude(m => m.RolePermissions)
                    .ThenInclude(m => m.Entity)
                    .ThenInclude(m => m.EntityArea)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

However, I do get the Role, I'm not getting anything further (Rolepermissions collection, Entity and Area).  Is there something fundamentally I am doing wrong?  This is a readonly query so hence notracking being used.

Thanks!

Comment: It is just a guess, but making ICollection `virtual` is not going to change the result?

Comment: hmmm I'll try it, but wouldn't making it virtual just change it to lazy loading instead of eager?

Comment: You may be right, but lazy loading can be disabled globally by `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` if you don't want it.

Comment: Or maybe we are talking different EF version. Is it EF Core or EF 6 and below?

Comment: this is EF Core

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything fundamentally wrong with your attempt. Have you checked if the specific user actually has any data in the connected tables?

Include() can sometimes generate a left join when you don't really need it, so I'd advise you to stay away from it when you can. I'd generally use a projection to specify the data I want to recieve. For your example this can be done with:

```
    dbUser = db.Users
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .Where(x => x.UserId == UserID)
                        .Select(x => new 
                        {
                          Role = x.Role,
                          RolePermissions = x.RolePermissions,
                          Entity = x.Entity,
                          EntityArea = x.EntityArea
                        })
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: yeah I double and triple checked to see if the related data exists correctly... pretty sure it does (Guess I';; go check one more time).  any reason why include and theninclude wouldn't return the expected data then?  It seems that "this should work"

Comment: You can check what kind of SQL your LINQ is generating by using this:

"context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;"

(or you can set it to a lambda that just concatenates the SQL to a local string variable)

After that you can run this in SQL Developer/Management Studio in order to examine which part of the query makes it so that you get no results.
After that you have a couple of options:
1) Tweak the LINQ query a few times, untill it produces the SQL that you need
or
2) Use pure SQL instead of EF